# Google VR View - Setting type of video

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, google-vr

So I am trying to use Google's VR SDK to play a video in my app however am having a few issues. Despite the documentation, it appears that we can no longer set the type of the video so I am getting the video displaying like this: [image]

I can't move it around at all like I should be able to. Also the parameters for full screen mode doesn't appear to be working. Does anyone know how this can be fixed? This is the code I am using:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "NewViewController.h"
#import "GVRVideoView.h"


@interface NewViewController ()
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet GVRVideoView *viewView;



@end

@implementation NewViewController {
    BOOL _isPaused;
}

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _viewView.enableFullscreenButton = YES;
    _viewView.enableCardboardButton = YES;

    _isPaused = true;

    // Load the sample 360 video, which is of type stereo-over-under.
    NSString *videoPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"congo" ofType:@"mp4"];
    [_viewView loadFromUrl:[[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:videoPath]];


}



#pragma mark - GVRVideoViewDelegate

- (void)widgetViewDidTap:(GVRWidgetView *)widgetView {
    if (_isPaused) {
        [_viewView resume];
    } else {
        [_viewView pause];
    }
    _isPaused = !_isPaused;
}

- (void)widgetView:(GVRWidgetView *)widgetView didLoadContent:(id)content {
    NSLog(@"Finished loading video");
}

- (void)widgetView:(GVRWidgetView *)widgetView
didFailToLoadContent:(id)content
  withErrorMessage:(NSString *)errorMessage {
    NSLog(@"Failed to load video: %@", errorMessage);
}

- (void)videoView:(GVRVideoView*)videoView didUpdatePosition:(NSTimeInterval)position {
    // Loop the video when it reaches the end.
    if (position == videoView.duration) {
        [videoView seekTo:0];
        [videoView resume];
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even I was facing same issue
So I changed

```
options.inputType = Options.TYPE_STEREO_OVER_UNDER;
```

To

```
Options options = new Options();
options.inputType = Options.TYPE_MONO;
```

So video is working fine now

Answer (score 2):

```
GVRVideoView have two type :
1) kGVRVideoTypeMono 
2) kGVRVideoTypeStereoOverUnder

/** Enum for video image types. */
typedef NS_ENUM(int, GVRVideoType) {
  // Each video frame is a monocular equirectangular panorama.
  // Each frame image is expected to cover 360 degrees along its horizontal axis.
  kGVRVideoTypeMono = 1,

  // Each video frame contains two vertically-stacked equirectangular panoramas. The top part of
  // the frame contains pixels for the left eye, while the bottom part of the frame contains
  // pixels for the right eye.
  kGVRVideoTypeStereoOverUnder,
};


If below method used : The video is assumed to be of type |kGVRVideoTypeMono|.
 - (void)loadFromUrl:(NSURL*)videoUrl;

If below method used then -The video type is set by |ofType:kGVRVideoTypeMono /kGVRVideoTypeStereoOverUnder|

- (void)loadFromUrl:(NSURL*)videoUrl ofType:(GVRVideoType)videoType;

e.g : [_videoView loadFromUrl:_videoURL ofType:kGVRVideoTypeMono];
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `loadFromUrl:` without a type passed defaults to `kGVRVideoTypeMono`.

The method signatures should answer your question:

```
/**
 * Load a local or remote video from a url and start playing.
 *
 * The video is assumed to be of type |kGVRVideoTypeMono|.
 */
- (void)loadFromUrl:(NSURL*)videoUrl;

/**
 * Load a local or remote video from a url and start playing.
 *
 * The video type is set by |videoType|.
 */
- (void)loadFromUrl:(NSURL*)videoUrl ofType:(GVRVideoType)videoType;
```